# function swapExactTokensForTokens - amountOutMin

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle, remix, uniswap

**I have assigned 'uint amountOutMin' as 1. But when I swap 0.1BNB  to btc, amoutOutMin will be less than 1. Will this transaction revert (since amountOutMin is <1). I belive we cannot set it to a value like 0.0001**

```
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
  uint amountIn,
  uint amountOutMin,
  address[] calldata path,
  address to,
  uint deadline
) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

**I am curious because I am getting the error message,**

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
reason="execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"
```

**I have approved the amounts for the router before hand, and the first transaction always goes through, and the subsequent transactions fails with the error message. The function is as follows**

```
function swap (address _router, address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint _amount) private onlyOwner {
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(_router,_amount);  // Approve router to spend.
    address[] memory path;  
    path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = _tokenOut;
    uint deadline = block.timestamp+300;
    IUniswapV2Router02(_router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amount,1,path, address(this), deadline);
}
```

I am trying to debug the error, and want to eleminate this as a potential culprit.